# How do I add a 3rd message type when I'm already using ListTile to simulate 2 different kinds of messages?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, widget

I am currently using a ListTile to simulate messages sent and received in a group chat. This is working great, but now I need to add the capability to include a 3rd type of message and I don't know if I can do so with ListTile or if I need to redo this from the ground up using `Rows` and `Containers`.

Right now, the condition simply checks to see if `uid == currentUID` to determine whether to show the message on the left or the right. I need to change this to check what type the message is and if it is of type `1`, then show the chat message in the middle. Otherwise, do the normal check on `uid == currentUID` to determine if it should be on the left or right.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: chats.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final isSelected = index == selectedIndex;
                final msg = ModelChatData.fromJson(chats[index]);
                final text = msg.text;
                final timestamp = msg.timestamp;
                final type = msg.type;
                var uid = '';
                var username = '';

                if (type == 0) { // regular message
                  uid = msg.uid!;
                  username = msg.username!;
                }

                if (type == 1) {
                   //do something that will allow the code below to show the chat message in the middle of the screen
                }

                return FractionallySizedBox(
                  widthFactor: 1, // set width of listtile
                  child: ListTile(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedIndex = isSelected ? null : index;
                      });
                    },
                    leading: uid == currentUID
                        ? const SizedBox.shrink()
                        : const CircleAvatar(child: FlutterLogo(),),
                    title: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: uid == currentUID
                          ? CrossAxisAlignment.end
                          : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          username,
                          style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    trailing: uid == currentUID
                        ? const CircleAvatar(child: FlutterLogo(),)
                        : const SizedBox.shrink(),
                    subtitle: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: uid == currentUID
                          ? CrossAxisAlignment.end
                          : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(text),
                        Visibility(
                          visible:
                          isSelected, // used for show/hide date when message is clicked on
                          child: Text(
                            DateTime.now().toString(),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add conditions to achieve this.....

```
....
type == 1 ?
             FractionallySizedBox(
                      widthFactor: 1, // set width of listtile
                      child: ListTile(
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            selectedIndex = isSelected ? null : index;
                          });
                        },
                        title: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            const CircleAvatar(
                              child: FlutterLogo(),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(width: 10),
                            Column(
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  'Username ${index + 1}',
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 16),
                                ),
                                Text('This is message ${index + 1}'),
                                Visibility(
                                  visible:
                                      isSelected, // used for show/hide date when message is clicked on
                                  child: Text(
                                    DateTime.now().toString(),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
       :  FractionallySizedBox(
                  widthFactor: 1, // set width of listtile
                  child: ListTile(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedIndex = isSelected ? null : index;
                      });
                    },
                    leading: uid == currentUID
                        ? const SizedBox.shrink()
                        : const CircleAvatar(child: FlutterLogo(),),
                    title: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: uid == currentUID
                          ? CrossAxisAlignment.end
                          : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          username,
                          style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    trailing: uid == currentUID
                        ? const CircleAvatar(child: FlutterLogo(),)
                        : const SizedBox.shrink(),
                    subtitle: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: uid == currentUID
                          ? CrossAxisAlignment.end
                          : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(text),
                        Visibility(
                          visible:
                          isSelected, // used for show/hide date when message is clicked on
                          child: Text(
                            DateTime.now().toString(),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
),
```

Your `ListView.builder` return above widget.